# Objective-C: How to perform a performSelector:@selector?

Tags: objective-c

Well, I'm creating a custom SEL like:

```
NSArray *tableArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"aaa", @"bbb", nil];
for ( NSString *table in tableArray ){
    SEL customSelector = NSSelectorFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"abcWith%@", table]);
    [self performSelector:customSelector withObject:0];
}
```

I got a error:
**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Sync aaaWithaaa]: unrecognized selector sent to instance**

but if i run it with the real method name it works!

```
[self performSelector:@selector(aaaWithaaa:) withObject:0];
```

How to solve it out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've already created selector from string - pass it to performSelector: method:

```
[self performSelector:customSelector withObject:0];
```

**Edit:** Mind, that if your method takes parameter then you **must** use colon when create selector from it:

```
// Note that you may need colon here:
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"abcWith%@:", table]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *tableArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"aaa", @"bbb", nil];

for ( NSString *table in tableArray ){
     SEL customSelector = NSSelectorFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"abcWith%@:", table]);
     [self performSelector:customSelector withObject:0];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Close.

The difference is that with `@selector(aaaWithaaa:)` you pass a method name but with `@selector(customSelector:)` you're passing a variable of type SEL (with a spare colon).

Instead, you just need:

```
[self performSelector:customSelector withObject:0];
```

The other difference is that you *write* your string with a colon at the end, but you `stringWithFormat:` has none. It's important; it means that the method takes a parameter. If your method has a parameter, it needs to be there, i.e.,

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"abcWith%@:", table]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (id)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anObject
```

First argument is `SEL` type.

```
SEL customSelector = NSSelectorFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"abcWith%@", table]);
[self performSelector:customSelector withObject:0];
```